# Is there a linux util for starting a process in the background in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I'm trying to do some alias magic with vim. I know that normally, appending an ampersand (`&`) to a command causes it to start in the background. Is there anything that lets me do that by prepending something as a util? In sum, instead of

```
alias gvim='gvim -f &'
```

I'd like to do this:

```
alias gvim='background gvim -f'
```

where `background` is some util.

Comment: Drive-by downvote, really? If you're going to downvote, please explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure *why* you'd bother, given the `&` operator, but you can write it yourself. Behold the script `background`:

```
#!/bin/sh

"$@" &
exit 0
```

Comment: I want to do this because the above alias would not work for `gvim foo.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

The alias doesn't work because any "arguments" to the alias are placed after the expansion of the alias, so with `alias gvim='gvim -f &'`,

```
gvim foo.txt
```

would expand to

```
gvim -f & foo.txt
```

with the ampersand getting between the command and its argument.

Instead of an alias, use a function:

```
gvim () {
    command gvim -f "$1" &
}
```